# dispatching wcf model - adding method

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

Sorry I still don't understand how UI works and what is `Dispatcher`

I have such `DispatchingWcfModel`:

```
public interface IWcfModel
{
    List<ConsoleData> DataList { get; set; }
    event Action<List<ConsoleData>> DataArrived;
}

class DispatchingWcfModel : IWcfModel
{

    private readonly IWcfModel _underlying;
    private readonly Dispatcher _currentDispatcher;

    public DispatchingWcfModel(IWcfModel model)
    {
        _currentDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        _underlying = model;
        _underlying.DataArrived += _underlying_DataArrived;
    }

    private void _underlying_DataArrived(List<ConsoleData> obj)
    {
        Action dispatchAction = () =>
        {
            if (DataArrived != null)
            {
                DataArrived(obj);
            }
        };
        _currentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, dispatchAction);
    }

    public List<ConsoleData> DataList
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public event Action<List<ConsoleData>> DataArrived;
}
```

Now I want to add `int[] ConnectionStats { get; set; }`. Should I introduce separate event for it? What should I write in DispatchingWcfModel? I want to have interface like that:

```
public interface IWcfModel
{
    List<ConsoleData> DataList { get; set; }
    int[] ConnectionStats { get; set; }
    event Action<List<ConsoleData>> DataArrived;
}
```

Comment: if you don't understand what it is you're working with, why are you trying to modify it?

Comment: i hope that I will be able to understand using these examples :)

Comment: Have you read [the reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

The `Dispatcher` is WPF's internal message queue for the main UI Thread. It can be used from other threads to run commands on the main UI thread of an application.

This is important because WPF doesn't let you access objects which were created on other threads. For example, if a Button is created on the main UI thread, then you cannot modify this button from another thread, but you can use the Dispatcher from another thread to send a command to the main UI thread to update the button.

This applies to all objects, not just UI Elements. If something like an `ObservableCollection` is created on one thread, another thread cannot modify it. Because of this, all objects are usually created on the main UI thread.

Dispatcher messages can get processed synchronously or asynchronously, and they can have different priorities . In your code, you're using `_currentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, dispatchAction);`, which means it will begin an asynchronous operation with the main UI thread, and run it at the same priority as DataBinding. You can view more information on `DispatcherPriorities` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx).

If your `ConnectionStats` collection gets its data asynchronously, then you will want to add some kind of DataArrived method that will take data obtained from a non-UI thread and add it to the collection. You can use the existing DataArrived method if the data is obtained and packaged together, or create your own if the data is obtained separately. If it gets it's data synchronously, you don't need to do anything special.

From the looks of things, `_underlying_DataArrived` is meant to run on a background thread (meaning it can't alter your collections, which should be created on the main UI thread), while `DataArrived` is meant to run on the main UI thread.